# Move multiple divs to other divs in a list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple repeating parent `div`s each containing a 'Date' `div` and an image container.

I want to move each 'Date' `div` in each parent to another location within the repeating element end using jQuery.

How is this possible? I've looked at other questions on here but nothing really works for me.

My repeating HTML is:

```
<div class="grid_12 featureEventWrap">

<div class="row">
  <div class="grid_8" style="padding-top: 20px">

    <div class="dateWrap">
      <h6>December</h6>
      <h5>14</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="featuredEvent">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <h3>Subtitle</h3>
      <p>Paragraph, paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid_4 featuredEventImage">
    <div class="featuredEventImageShad">
      <img src="images/news/1.jpg" width="270" height="175">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

This repeats multiple times down the page, but I want to move `.dateWrap` to be inside `.featuredEventImage` on each instance. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you also paste what you want the end result to look like?

Comment: You mean the `<div class="dateWrap">`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, should be easy as:

```
$('.featureEventWrap').each(function(){
    var $destination = $(this).find(' .destinationElement ');
    $(this).find(' .elementToMove ').appendTo( $destination );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/ 
http://api.jquery.com/find/ 
http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had got things moving around, but it was the .each function confusing me. Very informative.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.dateWrap').each(function() {
    $(this).parents('.row:first').find('.featuredEventImage').append(this);
});
```

Note: When you append an element inside another element, the first lose the original parent and it will moved into new object.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('.dateWrap').each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.featuredEventImage').append(this);
    });
```